# Azure DocumentDB Orderby not working with Partitioned collection

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

We have created a partitioned collection with MyID as partition Key  in azure DocumentDB and populated data in to the collection , but when we try to run a query with order by it fails,

Sample Query,
    `SELECT * 
     FROM Families f 
     JOIN c IN f.children 
     WHERE f.MyId = 123
     ORDER BY f.address.city ASC`

Please suggest on the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>DocumentDB supports cross-partition Order By only as a preview feature. You need to email askdocdb@microsoft.com to get access to it.</strike>

DocumentDB supports cross partition ORDER BY as of SDK 1.9.0+.